# Cordova plugins only work in iOS the second time its opened with a THREAD WARNING. How do you get plugins to initialize onload?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, plugins, inappbrowser

Cordova Plugins in my iOS application only work after you open the app, close it by going back to the home screen, then reopening the app. Then a THREAD WARNING displays in the XCode log.

```
2014-05-14 14:00:38.062 TLEMobile[28819:60b] THREAD WARNING: ['InAppBrowser'] took '192.306885' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
2014-05-14 14:01:18.919 TLEMobile[28819:60b] THREAD WARNING: ['Notification'] took '39.698975' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
```

What is causing this? And if I really need to set all the plugins as background threads how do you set that?

I have added this param to my config.xml for ios to force the plugin to load on open but that doesn't seem to work.

```
<param name="onload" value="true" />
```

I simply do not get it. I have tried reinstalling the platform as a whole. Individually removing all the plugins and putting them back and I am still getting the same issue. Plugins will only work when the app gets backgrounded and then brought back up. Here is the code from the recent build to ios as I start the app. It appears that the plugins load as th is starts but then are not accessible.

```
2014-05-22 15:39:40.817 TLEMobile[5199:60b] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2014-05-22 15:39:40.875 TLEMobile[5199:60b] Unlimited access to network resources
2014-05-22 15:39:41.131 TLEMobile[5199:60b] [CDVTimer][device] 0.559986ms
2014-05-22 15:39:41.136 TLEMobile[5199:60b] [CDVTimer][notification] 0.389040ms
2014-05-22 15:39:41.143 TLEMobile[5199:60b] [CDVTimer][inappbrowser] 3.835022ms
2014-05-22 15:39:41.149 TLEMobile[5199:60b] [CDVTimer][socialsharing] 1.318038ms
2014-05-22 15:39:41.153 TLEMobile[5199:60b] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 23.202002ms
2014-05-22 15:39:41.659 TLEMobile[5199:60b] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2014-05-22 15:39:41.664 TLEMobile[5199:60b] IAB.close() called but it was already closed.
2014-05-22 15:39:45.843 TLEMobile[5199:60b] Finished load of: file:///var/mobile/Applications/220DD603-0644-4290-AE21-F9B6041D8408/TLEMobile.app/www/index.html#/tab/home
2014-05-22 15:39:54.914 TLEMobile[5199:60b] THREAD WARNING: ['Device'] took '14.032959' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
2014-05-22 15:39:55.033 TLEMobile[5199:60b] THREAD WARNING: ['Notification'] took '100.118896' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
2014-05-22 15:40:00.716 TLEMobile[5199:60b] THREAD WARNING: ['Notification'] took '5541.863037' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
```

Comment: Does the behavior occur if you aren't debugging with Xcode? That is, if you launch the app on your device without Xcode attached, do you have to background it and resume it before any plugins work?

Comment: Also: you are waiting to use any cordova plugin until `deviceready` is fired, right?

Comment: @KerriShotts Yes this is happening when the device is not connected. I always have to background the app then reopen for the plugins to work.  I'm pretty sure I am since no plugins are active immediately. Plugins like the inappbrowser are only fired when a button is clicked and I assume the device is ready at that point

Comment: Do you have any other plugins other than IAP and Notification?

Comment: @KerriShotts yes I am also using a [SocialSharing](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin) as well as the Device plugin

Comment: I wouldn't imagine that those would be causing an issue, but try this: I know the app will probably fail, but see if you can remove all your plugins and then add them back one by one. That might indicate if a specific plugin is causing the issue.

Comment: @KerriShotts I have tried that and am still getting the error, I am really interested in the "Plugin should use a background thread." line

Comment: Several plugins complain about using background threads -- even the core plugins (such as Media). I don't think that it is related, except to show that something is mucking up with the initialization of the plugin (and thus triggering the warning). Do you have any code responding to the `pause` and `resume` events?

Comment: I do not currently. How can I log to the XCode logger on pause and resume event? Also thank you for sticking with this.

Comment: If you're not using `pause` or `resume`, then that can't be the issue -- but I was just checking to see if you were. What version of Cordova are you using? Also, are you using the most recent version of the plugins? Finally, what version(s) iOS are you targeting? Does the behavior occur when using the iOS simulator?

Comment: The newest Cordova 3.4. All the versions of the plugins are up to date. I am targetting iOS 7.1 and yes it also occurs in the simulator. I actually solved the problem the other day. I messed with a lot of things but am fairly certain what ultimately fixed it was changed the order of when my scripts were being called. I was using the Ionic Framework and it was being called in before cordova.js or any cordova specific scripts. It appears it had dependencies on cordova.js and when I switched the order it started working correctly.

Answer (score 6):

I had same issue. Today I've found solution for my case.

The problem was with js2native bridge. Cordova has different methods to communicate with native library (bridge mode):

- XHR with, w/o or optional payload;
- iframe hash with or w/o payload;
- iframe nav.

In cordova.js you can find iOSExec function. For iOS (except iOS 5) bridge mode is set to IFRAME_NAV.

Previous developer made couple of mistakes when on project design phase - and one of them is that whole content is removed from  when view changes. And cordova's  too. So cordova gets some error loops and plugins is not working.

The solution is to force XHR bridge mode. I've inserted next code right in my deviceready callback:

```
cordova.exec.setJsToNativeBridgeMode(cordova.exec.jsToNativeModes.XHR_NO_PAYLOAD);
```

I hope this will help you. Good luck.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me.  It it a real deal breaker for cordova ios.

Comment: This solution did end up working for me.  Call before anything in your deviceReady callback.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same symptoms on cordova-ios 3.9.2 but my root cause was different from others listed here. Turns out it was a content security policy issue, `gap://ready` is required for the iframe cordova bridge.

If none of the other solutions work for you, look at your content security policy and make sure to add `gap:` to the frame-src part of your `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"` tag.

Note: Xcode doesn't show any clue to fix this error but safari debugging shows the error very clearly.

Comment: Thank you. Previously my app worked without any problems when emulated on an Android AVD, but when I tried to emulate on iOS or on an real iOS device my Ionic 1 app only loaded a blank status bar and I had to click the Home button and re-open the app for it to fully load. I solved the problem following your advice of adding `frame-src self gap: gap://ready` in `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"` tag of my index.html. Note that **cordova-plugin-whitelist** documentation states: *gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication*

Comment: @LukeSchoen - I am facing the same problem as well. Can you please share me you meta tag for me to verify if I have added it correctly?  Thanks!

Comment: +1 I have been troubleshooting this for 3 days. I don't know how you even figured this out, I wouldn't have been able to. I didn't think it could have anything to do with frame-src, I did add it to the default at some point.