# Mobile app using cordova-plugin-firebase receives push notifcations on iOS only the second time it's opened

Tags: ios, cordova, firebase, cordova-plugins, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm developing a mobile app for Android and iOS with PhoneGap Build. The app should be able to communicate with Firebase and receive push notifications from there, so im using this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-firebase.
On Android, everything works fine, but on iOS, push notifications are not received until I close the app and open it a second time.

When I open the app for the first time, the `FirebasePlugin.grantPermission()` method works, so there's a message asking for permission to receive notifications, and when I use

```
window.FirebasePlugin.hasPermission(function(data){
    console.log(data.isEnabled);
});
```

`data.isEnabled` equals `true`. So, the plugin seems to be running, but no notifications are being received.

I found this related question: [Cordova plugins only work in iOS the second time its opened with a THREAD WARNING. How do you get plugins to initialize onload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23662121/cordova-plugins-only-work-in-ios-the-second-time-its-opened-with-a-thread-warnin), but none of the suggested solutions worked for me.
As mentioned there, I added

```
cordova.exec.setJsToNativeBridgeMode(cordova.exec.jsToNativeModes.XHR_NO_PAYLOAD);
```

at the beginning of the deviceReady callback, but the `setJsToNativeBridgeMode` method as well as `jsToNativeModes.XHR_NO_PAYLOAD` do not exist.
I also added `gap: gap://ready` after both `default-src` and `frame-src` inside the `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"` tag in index.html, but it didn't work.

Does someone have any idea how to explain and prevent this strange behavior? I'd really appreciate some help.