# Ionic View showing black screen after splash screen on iPhone 5

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-native

My app is working successfully with ionic v1 on ios and android devices with all versions. But iphone 5 shows black screen after splash screen when the application work first time. Then it works properly.
How can I solve this problem?

My development environment:

cli packages: 
    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1

global packages:
    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:
    Cordova Platforms : android 6.4.0 ios 4.4.0
    Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.3.2

Comment: got the same issue. Is there any kind of this error in android?

Comment: There is the solution. Thanks for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35004922/5589082

Comment: Can you show what did you exactly did to solve this issue in the answer section. Thank you

Comment: Before : <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *; ">   After : <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *; frame-src 'self' gap://ready">  I have just added this(content="frame-src 'self' gap://ready") and it worked

Comment: In which file? index.html?

Comment: Yes, in index.html